# Posible hacer ARRAY de tipo CLASE basado en TEMPLATES?

Tags: c++, array, class

> Intentando desarrollar una clase Cola para la universidad me he topado con el siguiente error:

He pensado en hacer dos clases, la clase "Nodo" y la clase "Cola".
La clase nodo tendra' el dato de un tipo sin especificar (ya que usare' un template con el nombre Tbase) y la clase Cola contendra' un puntero a un array creado del tipo nodo donde se ira'n almacenando los nodos y desde el que se podra' manejar.

```cpp
template<typename Tbase>
class Nodo{
private:
    Tbase dato;
    Nodo* siguiente;
    Nodo* anterior;
public:
    Tbase getDato();
    void setDato(Tbase);
    Nodo* getSiguiente();
    void setSiguiente(Nodo*);
    Nodo* getAnterior();
    void setAnterior(Nodo*);
};

// CLASE COLA:

class Cola{
private:
    int TAM = 10;
    // Puntero a array de forma dinamica;
    Nodo* array = new Nodo[TAM];
public:

};
```

> A lo mejor no puedo hacer un array de clases con templates, NO lo se'.

Comment: ¿ Cual es la pregunta ? ¿ El resultado obtenido no es el resultado esperado ? ¿ Obtienes un error de ejecución ? ¿ Un error de compilación ? ¿ Cual es el mensaje completo de dicho error ?

Answer (score 0):

Nodo requiere el tipo de dato del template: En la clase Nodo debes referenciar todos los Nodo* como Nodo referrnciando al tipo Tbase.

Cuando haces una clase plantilla tienes que referenciar el tipo de dato que requiere la plantilla.

Si defines

```
     template<typename tbase>
     class Nodo
```

Entonces no puedes referirte a la clase Nodo sin especificarle el paramerro de plantilla que requiere;

```
         Nodo nodo; // error Nodo requiere un tipo de dato
         Nodo<int> nodo; // ok nodo de entero
         Nodo<std:string> *pnode; // puntero a un nodo de string.
```

Tu array también está mal definido.

Te recomendaria que si estás aprendiendo c++ utilices la STL que ya implementan vectores, colas, listas, pilas, etc. por que la verdad no creo que hoy en día alguien implemente su propia clase nodo, lista, etc . Salvo que sea un caso excepcional.